# Wake windows pc from Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS not working using wakeonlan utility

Tags: wakeonlan

I have a strage issue with wakeonlan ubuntu utility. When I shutdown windows station and immediately try to wake it up using wakeonlan from ubuntu, it works, but after a while, issuing the same command (wakeonlan -i 192.168.8.4 D4:3D:7E:95:C1:79) it won't wake the computer.
I have to mention that I tried to wake that computer from other windows station using a GUI windows program and works perfectly any time.
All computers are on the same lan, connected to the same switch.
Maybe has to do with ubuntu ARP cache, I don't know, why wakeonlan is working fine shortly after shutting down windows pc and after some time is not doing anything?
Can you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a Windows problem to me, which then would be better asked on [su].

Comment: It could be your PC WoL feature t be buggy. Can you test it with another working WoL-capable PC?

Comment: Dear all, unfortunately is not a windows problem, nor a buggy WoL feature. I tried to wake up another windows pc using wakeonlan ubuntu utility and the behavior is the same - after some time it won't wake up, but from a windows wol pc utility is working fine. Thank you for the answers! However, I will try with another linux pc, maybe another distribution and see what happens because the issue seems to be with the linux machine that is sending wol packets and not with windows computers since they can be wake up from other windows wol utilities.

Comment: You might find [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) useful.

Comment: With wakeonlan ubuntu utility is not working, but I tried with ethtool - sudo etherwake -i interface_name MAC_address and voila, computers are starting fine. With wakeonlan was more comfortable because using ethtool requires sudo and you have to enter the password, but I'll live with that.